# How to format C# "else" onto one line in Rider

Tags: rider, jetbrains-rider

How can I get `else` to be on one line as it should be? (meaning `} else {` instead of the version shown below).

I am already using K&R style which fixes all other uses of braces (as shown below), but it does not fix the `else`.

[image: Bad Format]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a toggle in the "Editor" > "Code Style" > "C#" settings under the "Line Breaks and Wrapping" tab called "Place 'else' on new line":
[image]

Disabling this will achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you! I knew this had to be user error!

Comment: ...that's nice, but sometimes (e.g. when the else block is too long) I still want it to be on a separate line. Is there a way to disable that kind of re-formatting / shifting of else blocks?